# Getting wrong special characters reading docx files

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the text from a .docx using the following code, but the problem is that the text contains special characters (e.g. "ç" or "á"), and the code is not reading the file correclty.

```
try:
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import XML
except ImportError:
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
import zipfile


"""
Module that extract text from MS XML Word document (.docx).
(Inspired by python-docx <https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx>)
"""

WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
PARA = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'


def get_docx_text(path):
    """
    Take the path of a docx file as argument, return the text in unicode.
    """
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
    document.close()
    tree = XML(xml_content)

    paragraphs = []
    for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
        texts = [node.text
                 for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
                 if node.text]
        if texts:
            paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))

    return '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = def_get_docx_text('teste.docx')
    print doc.split('\n')
```

In this short example, the original text is like this:

```
A titulação genérica de Administração Pública
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
01 A titula\xe7\xe3o gen\xe9rica de Administra\xe7\xe3o
```

Comment: That is *correct output* for printing a list. You are getting `u'A titula\xe7\xe3o gen\xe9rica de Administra\xe7\xe3o'`, **note the quotes**.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a *list*; in Python, container contents are then displayed using the `repr()` output. `u'A titula\xe7\xe3o gen\xe9rica de Administra\xe7\xe3o'` is Python string literal syntax for a Unicode string value; this format is designed for debugging purposes and can be pasted directly into a Python interpreter to re-create the original value without having to worry about encoding issues:

```
>>> line = u'A titula\xe7\xe3o gen\xe9rica de Administra\xe7\xe3o'
>>> line
u'A titula\xe7\xe3o gen\xe9rica de Administra\xe7\xe3o'
>>> print line
A titulação genérica de Administração
```

Print the individual strings instead:

```
for line in doc.split('\n'):
    print line
```

or re-join the string, with spaces for example:

```
print ' '.join(doc.split('\n'))
```

Comment: I'm afraid the error is in the reading of the docx file, because when I print the whole doc var, I already get wrong characters @Martin Pieter

Comment: @user3511563: Then *show the actual output*. What you shared is not the actual output; the `[..]` list syntax is missing, as are the quotes and the `u''` prefixes that I know must be there.

Comment: @user3511563: The unquoted content you showed *contains the right characters*.